# JPA: how to have relationships with only IDs instead of Objects?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, rest, jpa

While using JPA, is it possible to have a `@OneToMany` relationship with another entity and keep only the Set of the IDs instead of a Set of Objects?

e.g., when dealing with **Books** and **Libraries** I will have something like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Library")
public class Library {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and setters
}

@Entity(name = "Book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

This is ok and works fine, at least until I need to share the Library entity through REST APIs.
When moving the Library's JSON (in both ways, Server-->Client & Client-->Server) I would like to avoid passing the list of Books Objects, but instead just pass and receive the list of Books IDs (`List<Long>`), and still being able to perform basic CRUD operations through the JPARepository.

This way it would be possible to reduce the size of the shared JSON and also have a lower coupling between the entities.

Is it possible to have such a **light-weight relationship** between entities in JPA?

I would like to have the **Library** entity as below:

```
@Entity(name = "Library")
public class Library {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Set<Long> books = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Not the correct question. Your question is about marshalling JSON not mucking up JPA. There is plenty of material here about customizing marshalling. Recommend looking into DTOs, JSON annotations, and custom mappers.

Comment: But I want to have a List<Long> bookIDs; in java too, not only in the returned JSON

Comment: @1Z10 Then you loose the ability to traverse from Library to Book (and near all JPA features). But just map them as a `@ElementCollection` and you should be fine.

Comment: Yea, nothing is preventing you from persisting a List of ID's or creating one during runtime in Java, so it really depends on your use case. Your talking about REST interfaces and I've always left JPA to do its thing and marshalled the way I needed, typically with DTOs. Its a common pattern in REST applications.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, I got the point. I need to study DTOs, any hint/link from where to start?

Comment: It's more complicated than first glance so get a book and start there. DTO's, security, load balancing, gateways, contracts, asynchronous calls, and underlying database design. REST services are (part of) an application decomposition pattern so let that lead to a monolithic versus microservices guide.

Comment: https://github.com/karlnicholas/RestPractice if interested in Spring stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Passing entities to Controller is not a good idea. You should always think of converting entities to dto-s. Also, I would not recommend having ids on the controller level, as someone may take your ids and grab the whole database by them. This is extremely insecure.